# Como guardar valor de uma variável em uma função Bash Script

Tags: bash

Estou  criando uma fábrica para que seja facilmente cifrado um arquivo neste caso em txt ou decifrar. O problema neste programa é valor da variável CIFRA_HEX e CIFRA que não consigo passar o valor guardado para a seguinte função (decifra_RC4() ) não sendo possível decifrar o ficheiro.
Como posso resolver essa situação para que consiga obter o valor das chaves na função ?
O código implementado está em Bash Script

```
    menu(){
case $opcao_menu in
1)echo "REVERSE CRYPTO 4" ;;
esac

echo "1 -> Cifrar"
echo "2 -> Decifrar"
echo "3 -> Voltar ao menu anterior"
echo "Escolha uma das seguintes opções:"

read opcao

case $opcao in
0);;    
1) cifrar_RC4 ;;
2) decifrar_RC4;;
esac
}


cifrar_RC4() {
nome="RC4"

echo -n "Introduza a chave de cifra que pertende criar:"; read CIFRA
CIFRA_HEX= openssl rand -hex 8 

if [[ -z "$CIFRA" ]]; then
echo $CIFRA_HEX
fi

echo -n "introduza o nome do ficheiro para cifrar:"; read ENTRADA_FICHEIRO 
echo -n "Introduza o nome para o ficheiro de saida cifrado:"; read SAIDA_FICHEIRO
echo -n "Deseja remover o ficheiro original?"

if [[ -z "$ENTRADA_FICHEIRO" ]]; then
echo "O ficheiro foi encriptado"    
fi

case $opcao_menu in
1) algoritmo_cifraRC4 ;;
2) algoritmo_cifraAES128 ;;
3) algoritmo_cifraAES256 ;;
esac

#read opcao

valor_chave=$CIFRA_HEX
echo "A cifra utilizada foi: " $nome

if [[ -z "$CIFRA" ]]; then

echo "A chave gerada foi: " $valor_chave
else
echo "A chave criada foi: " $CIFRA
fi

echo "O ficheiro criado foi:" $SAIDA_FICHEIRO



}

decifrar_RC4() {

echo -n "introduza o nome do ficheiro para decifrar:"; read SAIDA_FICHEIRO
echo -n "Introduza o nome para o ficheiro de saida:"; read ENTRADA_FICHEIRO

case $opcao_menu in
1) algoritmo_decifraRC4 ;;
2) algoritmo_decifraAES128 ;;
3) algoritmo_decifraAES256 ;;
esac

if [[ -z "$CIFRA" ]]; then
echo "A chave usada foi: " $CIFRA_HEX
else
echo "A chave usada foi: " $CIFRA
fi
echo "O ficheiro de saida foi: " $ENTRADA_FICHEIRO


}


algoritmo_cifraRC4(){
if [[ -z "$CIFRA" ]]; then
openssl enc -rc4 -e -K "$CIFRA_HEX" -in "$ENTRADA_FICHEIRO.txt" -out "$SAIDA_FICHEIRO.rc4"
else
openssl enc -rc4 -e -K "$CIFRA" -in "$ENTRADA_FICHEIRO.txt" -out "$SAIDA_FICHEIRO.rc4"
fi
}

algoritmo_decifraRC4(){ 
echo $valor_chave
if [[ -z "$CIFRA" ]]; then
openssl enc -rc4 -d -K "$CIFRA_HEX" -in "$SAIDA_FICHEIRO.rc4" -out "$ENTRADA_FICHEIRO.txt"
else
openssl enc -rc4 -d -K "$CIFRA" -in "$SAIDA_FICHEIRO.rc4" -out "$ENTRADA_FICHEIRO.txt"
fi
}
menu
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Único erro que vi no teu código foi **`CIFRA_HEX= openssl rand -hex 8`** se vc deseja colocar o resultado do comando dentro da variável deve fazer asim

> CIFRA_HEX=$(openssl rand -hex 8)

veja o resultado:

> echo $CIFRA_HEX
>
> 2e7918cf12d2f50e

ou assim

> CIFRA_HEX=`openssl rand -hex 8`
>
> echo $CIFRA_HEX
>
> 2e7918cf12d2f50e

se quer o conteúdo como string, deve colocar entre aspas simples

> CIFRA_HEX='openssl rand -hex 8'
>
> echo $CIFRA_HEX
>
> openssl rand -hex 8